# Nothing happened when i run db:seed on Heroku

Tags: ruby, activerecord, heroku, sinatra

My app is made by Sinatra any everything working fine on my local server.
But when i deployed to Heroku and i ran this command

```
$ heroku run rake db:seed
```

Nothing happened even this command worked fine.

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

So this is my seed code

```
require_relative '../app/models/question'
require_relative '../app/models/answer'
require_relative '../app/models/user'
require 'faker'

class TaskSeed
    def self.faker
        20.times do 
            Question.create(
                :content => Faker::Lorem.sentence(200, true), 
                :headline => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
                :user_id => Faker::Number.between(1, 10)
                ) 
        end

        40.times do 
            Answer.create(
                :content => Faker::Lorem.sentence(20, true), 
                :headline => Faker::Lorem.sentence,
                :user_id => Faker::Number.between(1, 10),
                :question_id => Faker::Number.between(1, 10)
                ) 
        end

        20.times do
            User.create(
                :username => Faker::Internet.user_name, 
                :email => Faker::Internet.email,
                :encrypted_password => Faker::Internet.password(10, 20)
                ) 
        end

        vote_type_arr = ['up','down'] 

        50.times do
            QuestionVote.create(
                :type => vote_type_arr[rand(0..1)],
                :question_id => Faker::Number.between(1, 20)
                ) 
        end
    end
end

TaskSeed.faker
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

---

i am using PostgreSQL as my local since the project was made.

Comment: Do you mean that no output is produced or that those tables are still empty? As an aside I would use create! to avoid silent failures due to validations.

Comment: i mean the table still empty i guess. Because they not return any text in the console and i got Internal error on every pages that need to contact the table.

Comment: Rather than guessing, check the contents of the table (in the rails console for example). Errors could easily be because nothing guarantees that the values you are putting in question_id (for example) are in fact the ids of questions.

Answer (score 0):

If your local database is clean(no testing data), then you could try `heroku db:push`

If you are using the default PostgreSQL, try

```
heroku pg:reset
heroku rake db:seed
```

Comment: i am using PostgreSQL as my local.
I tried that one but didn't work too.